# Not able to connect to local network

Tags: wireless, networking

I have installed Kubuntu. I am able to connect to Internet and able to access external sites, but in my local network I have bugzila installed that I am not able to access, even I am not able to ping the gateway also `192.168.1.1`.
Below is the result of ifconfig command:

```
~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:70:f4:da:f9:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:81131 (81.1 KB)  TX bytes:81131 (81.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:5d:43:2e:1c:79  
          inet addr:192.168.1.26  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a5d:43ff:fe2e:1c79/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1909441 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:393292 (393.2 KB)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Which interface is connected to the internet? "eth0" or "wlan0"? 
Did you add "gateway" IP to both interfaces? If so, remove gateway IP from the local interface.

Comment: Thanks for reply Hasan , wlan0 is connected to the internet , i had added the gateway for eth0, which i have removed now as you suggested , but still i am not able to access any machine in the local network .

Comment: I have removed all the content of /etc/network/interfaces file and restart the network now i am able to access the internal network also . Thanks

Comment: @Roopesh Since you've solved your problem, and apparently done so in a way not suggested by the existing answer, you should [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) with the solution, so it's clear to people searching with similar problems how you fixed this. (You can mark your own answer as accepted 2 days after posting it.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two equal networks with address: `192.168.1.0/24` on two network interfaces: eth0 and wlan0. And it seems a gateway you are using configured toward the Internet but have no connection with your local network.

- You need to configure your wi-fi router for different network address: `192.168.2.0/24` or something else.
- Check your routes table by command: `ip route`
- You could see similar record: 

  `default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlx8c882b131d84 proto dhcp metric 600`
- `192.168.1.0/24` local network with Bugzilla should be accessible from now because of there are no conflicting networks present anymore.