# No Ethernet on Lenovo P50, (`ifplugstatus` reports unplugged) Intel I219-LM network card

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet

### Issue

On a Lenovo P50, the network card does not seem to be able to detect Ethernet cables or establish a network connection. The ethernet conection is set-up to be hot-plugged and managed by `avahi`. The wired connection once worked, but seems to have failed some time in the past six months or so.

### Debugging so far

- Computing support confirms that network ports are working
- Other machines plugged into network ports work, indicating cables are good
- Plugging in ethernet cables to laptop *does not* cause port to light up (but it is not clear that this port has lights)
- Wireless connection works
- Network configuration appears ok, common pitfalls not present

### System information

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-112-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-010) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) ) #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018
```

```
$ lspci | grep Ethernet
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 3a
       serial: [MAC_ADDRESS]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-112-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=172.20.174.88 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:133 memory:c4c00000-c4c01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: [MAC_ADDRESS]
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:130 memory:c5700000-c571ffff
```

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:7b:9d:e4:d8:49  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:c5700000-c5720000 

enp0s31f6:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:7b:9d:e4:d8:49  
          inet addr:[IP_ADDRESS]  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 Memory:c5700000-c5720000 
...
```

```
$ ifplugstatus
lo: link beat detected
enp0s31f6: unplugged
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

```
$ sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup -v enp0s31f6
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/[MAC_ADDRESS]
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/[MAC_ADDRESS]
Sending on   Socket/fallback
Configuring interface enp0s31f6=enp0s31f6 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant

/sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.enp0s31f6.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp0s31f6.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.enp0s31f6.leases enp0s31f6  
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/[MAC_ADDRESS]
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/[MAC_ADDRESS]
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xf5fca319)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0xf5fca319)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xf5fca319)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

```
$ sudo ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [MAC_ADDRESS] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet [IP_ADDRESS]/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link enp0s31f6:avahi
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### The following questions with similar symptoms do not resolve the issue:

#### Suggested solutions that do not work in this case:

The [suggested command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942712/ethernet-problem-lan-cable-appears-unplugged) `ip link set enp1s0 up` does not resolve it. The [suggested commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910378/error-showing-ethernet-cable-unplugged-in-ubuntu-14-04) `ifconfig .. down` ... `up` do not resolve it.

#### Similar symptoms, but probably unrelated hardware issues:

This issue is common with Realtek cards, and there are several related questions ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604473/ethernet-not-working-says-cable-unplugged-on-ubuntu-gnome-14-10)[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227078/problems-with-wired-ethernet-connection-ubuntu-11-10)[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478036/ubuntu-wont-connect-to-network-through-ethernet/521342#521342)[4](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1709957)), but this machine has an Intel card.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243076/usb-ethernet-adapter-cable-unplugged-message-while-plugged-in)
seems specific to a USB Ethernet device, related to hot-plug issues.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595628/usb-ethernet-not-being-redetected-after-unplugging) involves the network interface disappearing entirely, and returning on reboot.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156957/after-upgrading-from-11-10-to-12-04-i-dont-have-ethernet-connection-how-to-sol) is a bit vague and lacks definitive answers.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802975/ethernet-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-in-dual-boot-system) pertains to Ethernet, but the answer is a link to wifi troubleshooting.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299238/ethernet-not-detected-whatsoever) appears to be different, as it involves the Ethernet adapter being unavailable, wheres it is available on my machine but registers as disconnected.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384607/network-cable-unplugged-message-after-motherboard-change) has similar symptoms, but was due to a conflicting configuration from a previous network card.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995660/enp0s31f6-cable-unplugged) related to a corrupted driver (I think?).

[In this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145429/not-able-to-connect-to-local-network?rq=1) they were able to regain network access simply by deleting `/etc/network/interfaces` and rebooting. I have tried this and it did not work in this case.

#### Potentially related questions without resolution

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946108/ethernet-not-detected-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) may be related (unclear), but does not have an answer. 
Likewise for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615685/ethernet-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-from-14-10-to-15-04).

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928080/cannot-connect-to-internet-via-lan-wireless-is-ok?rq=1) it was assumed that the problem lay with the building network configuration. I have been assured by the building support staff that this is not the case here.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950450/cannot-get-ethernet-to-work-with-ubuntu-16-04) was diagnosed as a hardware fault of the network card. It is not clear that it applies in this case. [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163651/why-cant-i-get-a-wired-connection-to-my-new-router) seemed also to be a hardware failure. (I would like to rule out other explanations before presuming hardware failure).

### Update and resolution

We determined that the machine could not use Ethernet when booted from a different operating system on removable media, indicating a hardware issue. Indeed, on the Lenovo P50 there *are* status LEDs (yellow and green) on the port, and these should respond when Ethernet is plugged in. They were dark on this machine, indicating a hardware issue.

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup -v enp0s31f6`

Comment: As a test, have you tried removing the allow-hotplug option from your config file and using auto enp0s31f6. Is it critical that you use this methind, can you not use network-manager (it does have a cli tool).

Comment: Please add `sudo ip a` stdout in your message.  Then you say "The suggested command `ip link set enp1s0 up`" I assume that you used `enp0s31f6`. If not that would explain why you cannot bring the interface up.

Comment: @chili555: added to question, hope it is helpful. @hatterman thanks, however I still see no connection with `auto enp0s31f6`. @kcdtv: added the output of said command to question, hope it helps. Yes the command was run using `enp0s31f6`, and double checked just now. Thanks!

Comment: hello @kcdtv,  would you perhaps happen to have further thoughts on how to fix this? I have not been able to make progress on the issue.

Comment: All I can suggest is to install network-manager, and then run the ncurses tool 'nmtui', see if you can set it up that way.

Comment: What is the result if you change: `allow-hotplug enp0s31f6` to read: `auto enp0s31f6` and then reboot. Do you connect? Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp` As the result will be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 thank you! I tried switching it to `auto`, but was not able to establish an ethernet connection. The `dmesg` output is not very long, it is pasted at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hnbBpj7t7f/

Comment: Thank you @hatterman, I have explored `nmtui`, and noticed nothing strange about the enp0s31f6 connection. When I try to "activate" that connection, I get the message `Could not activate connection: Connection 'Wired connection 1' is not available on the device enp0s31f6 at this time.` Any ideas of what to explore / set in `nmtui` that might help?

Comment: Did you remove your config for your LAN card from /etc/network/interfaces, then reboot and try nmtui ?

Comment: Ah no, I did not delete the existing configuration first, I will try that.

Comment: I deleted `/etc/network/interfaces`, rebooted, and set the ethernet connection via `nmtui` to `automatic` for ipv4, no connection. I also tried adding `automatic` for ipv6, no connection. I tried disabling wireless and rebooting again, still no connection.

Comment: Did you tried to execute `sudo dhclient enp0s31f6` in order to get the IP? (and do not have as we can see in `sudo ip a` stdout) Do you get one doing so?

Comment: I dont think you should delete /etc/network/interfaces, only the 2 lines within it that relate to your specific card.

Comment: It is possible that the lan card has failed at a hardware level. Boot from a live CD, does the network work ?

Comment: Another suggestion, boot into recovery mode from the grub menu, select enable networking, then select drop to a root shell. Does networking work ?

Comment: And another suggestion, boot using a different kernel from the grub menu, does networking work ?

Comment: Thank you friends, booting from a memory stick did not restore the network. I believe it is simply a hardware fault!